# The code keeps repeating kahoot numbers are added when it adds up

Tags: python

I am trying to find Kahoot codes, but when they are added up things are completely wacky (hard to explain but I will give the output at the end). edit: I forgot I had threading so i added it

```py
from kahoot import client  
import requests
import time
import threading

def print_epoch(nameOfThread, delay):
  bruh = 0
  while bruh <= 7:
#    time.sleep(delay)
    bruh += 1
    print(nameOfThread, "---------", time.time())

def kahoot_join(num): 
  code = 100
  while code <= 1428567:
    converted_code = str(code) 
    request = requests.get("https://kahoot.it/reserve/session/" + converted_code)
    code += 1
    print(code)  # what is being outputed to show what numbers are being requested and checked.
    if request.status_code == 200:
      bot = client()
      bot.join(converted_code, "bot")
      def joinHandle():
        pass
      bot.on("joined", joinHandle)
      print(joinHandle, code)

count = 0
while (count < 1):
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=kahoot_join, args=(2,))

    t1.start()
```

Output:

```
5714269
5714269
5714269
5714270
5714270
5714269
5714270
5714271
5714271
5714270
5714271
5714269
5714272
```

Comment: What's `joinHandle`? Seems like the code is creating multiple threads.

Comment: @gshpychka I don't actually know but it comes from the Pypi library KahootPY to join a Kahoot game with a code.